# такой вопрос, почему в регистр dx не записывается 2 часть отрицательного числа?

Tags: ассемблер

как я понял при переполнении число записывается в 2 регистрах AX, DX, но в моем случае просто записывается часть в AX, а в dx ничего не записывается.

```
    data segment
        a dw 60231
        b dw 30132
        c dw 15712
        x dw ?
        rez dd 0
data ends

code segment
    assume cs: code, ds: data
    start:
        mov ax, data
        mov ds, ax
        mov AX, b    ; Загрузить значение b в регистр AX
        mov BX, a    ; Загрузить значение a в регистр BX
        mov CX, 4    ; Загрузить значение C в регистр CX
        
        sal bx, 1   ; Умножить значение A на 2 (BX = 2A)
        mov word ptr rez, bx
        jnc dop1
        adc word ptr rez+2,0
        dop1:
            mul cx;  умножаем значение b на 4
            mov word ptr rez, ax
            jnc dop2
            adc word ptr rez+2,0
            dop2:
                add ax, b; 4b+1
                mov word ptr rez, ax
                jnc dop3
                adc word ptr rez+2,0
                dop3:
                    add ax,bx; 5B+ 2A
                    mov word ptr rez, ax
                    jnc dop4
                    adc word ptr rez+2,0
                    dop4:
                        add ax,c 
                        
                        mov word ptr rez, ax
                        jnc dop5
                        adc word ptr rez+2,0
                        dop5:
                            
                            neg ax ; делаем результат отрицательным
                            

                            mov word ptr rez, ax
                            jnc dop6
                            adc word ptr rez+2,0
                            dop6:
                                mov word ptr x,ax
                                mov word ptr x+2,dx
quit:
        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h

code ends
end start
```

Comment: Вы в dx ничего и не записываете. Опишите проблему конкретно, чтобы не нужно было догадываться, что вы имели в виду.

Comment: а разве если число выходит за рамки 16 бит оно не должно записываться в dx, ибо у меня после изменения знака выходит: FFFB 9F8E и 9F8E  в аx записывается, но не записывается в dx

Comment: dx - это отдельный регистр. При каких-то операциях (например, при умножении), в него может попадать часть результата, насколько я помню. Но в целом при переполнении ax в dx само по себе ничего не должно попадать. Но опять же, нужно смотреть конкретные операции, возможно есть какие-то нюансы.

Comment: а не подскажете, как записать в регистр dx старшую часть результата?

Comment: Сначала напишите, что вы хотите получить. Я по вашему коду попытался понять, но у вас тут бессмысленная каша. Куча ненужных jnc, всё время перезаписывается rez, в то время как к rez+2 добавляется перенос, пихаете в x+2 dx, когда x у вас - dw... Короче, код некорректен, вот и нет результата.

Comment: *а разве если число выходит за рамки 16 бит оно не должно записываться в dx* С чего бы? Вот если умножать два 16-битных (скажем, `mul cx`) - то да, результат пишется в DX:AX. Не при переполнении, а безусловно. Во всех остальных случаях никакого "переноса при переполнении" нет.

Comment: реализовать уравнение(Х= - (С + 2А + 4В + В)) на ассемблере, при этом числа даются почти максимальные, что бы было переполнение, т.к я только начал изучать язык не совсем понимаю что и куда вставлять

Comment: *не совсем понимаю что и куда вставлять* `JC print_error_message`

Answer (score 1):

`NEG` выполняет отрицание только одного регистра. Если вам нужно поменять знак длинного числа - `NEG` подходит только для младшей части, для старших нужно использовать комбинацию `NOT`+`ADC`. Например:

```
neg ax
not dx
adc dx,0
```

Обратите внимание, что перед `ADC` с нулевым операндом не нужно делать `JNC` - проверка CF уже заложена в инструкцию.

---

Кроме того, в вашем коде ошибка - вы собираете переносы в `res+2`, но никогда их не используете.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае в процессоре есть флаг переполнения, который устанавливается, если в результате какой-либо операции происходит переполнение. Так же в него приходит значение при операциях сдвига. Вот этим и воспользуйтесь для формирования старшей части результата.

[Флаги состояния и условные переходы](https://metanit.com/assembler/tutorial/2.5.php)